# Black screen in recovery mode after adding xorg.conf.d file

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, brightness

I’ve looked at a bunch of the existing questions about black screen and I don’t think this is a duplicate.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a Lenovo P52 ThinkPad.

I followed the instructions in [this article](https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/) to try to fix the screen brightness adjustment (which wasn’t working at all). Running `ls /sys/class/backlight` yielded `nvidia_0`. I then ran `ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` which yielded several different files that followed the pattern `10-*.conf`, including `10-nvidia.conf`. At this point I should have figured out what the `10-` and `20-` prefixes actually mean, but instead I went ahead and created `20-nvidia.conf` and saved it with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "nvidia"
        Option      "Backlight"  "nvidia_0"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Then I logged out, but was not able to log back in (I would be prompted to enter my password, and then just returned to the account selection screen once I entered it). I rebooted the computer, but now I get a black screen whenever I boot using any advanced or normal option (including all available recovery modes). I’ve tried editing the boot options to add `nomodeset` to the normal boot and remove it from recovery mode (which already had it), as well as trying `CTRL+ALT+F1` and `CTRL+ALT+F7` from the black screen with no success.

At this point it seems like “you bricked your OS, try reinstalling Ubuntu” might be the only answer, which would suck as I’m currently on the road and unable to do that.

Comment: First boot from Live USB and see if that works.